# FacebookCore Swift Compiler Error on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

This issue started yesterday after I updated my Xcode to 10.0.

I'm getting a Swift Compiler Error on file Pods > FacebookCore > SDKSettings.swift as the image below.

[image]

I have already tried to update cocoapods, my current version is 1.5.3.

I have tried to update FacebookCore, but the version didn't change (0.3.0).

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.

I haven't notice that when you add the pods FacebookCore and FacebookLogin, it automatically adds FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit as a dependency.

For some weird reason, if you only run the command `pod update FacebookCore`, it won't update the dependency FBSDKCoreKit or FacebookCore. So, you need to first run the command `pod update FBSDKCoreKit` and after that `pod update FacebookCore`. So it will update FacebookCore to 0.4.0. In this version, my project compiles without errors. I did the same with FBSDKLoginKit and FacebookLogin.